# Azure Kubernetes Pod to access NAS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nas

Background : I have a node.js application running in AKS. Now, customer is asking to upload file from this application into a NAS, for which the hostname, share name details are shared. I tried smbclient from my dev VM and it is working fine. When I tried the same in pod it is not. Both have same OS(centOS), same smb.conf configurations.

Command : smbclient -c "mkdir \"test_folder/test1\"" //xxx.abc.com/share_dev/ -U '' --password ''

What should I check for or how should I debug? Any clue would be highly helpful. Please do let me know if there any other ways for achieving the same.

Comment: What error are you getting? Is ping working between POD and NAS?

Comment: Yes, ping is working. Even "smbclient -L <sharename> is working.". The error is simply NT_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR. Then I included debug option in the command which then gives "SPNEGO login failed: {Operation Failed} The requested operation was unsuccessful.
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
has context menu"